# Run Pinax without VirtualEnv

Tags: django, virtualenv, pinax

Is there a way to run Pinax without virtualenv?

I want to run it without virtualenv as I want to run it on a django-container on mediatemples grid-hosting service. Their containers can scale upto 1Gb of dedicated memory, so I wouldnt have to worry about my own VPS or scaling issues. But their response was:

" because of the way the DjangoContainer works, you won't be able to configure your server to use your virtualenv.  Essentially the DjangoContainer is a virtualized server (to which you don't have access other than the AccountCenter tools, or the 'mtd' command line tool) with the specific purpose of serving your Django applications.  It mounts your django container folder so that it has your application code, but you cannot modify the version or location of python it uses.  This probably means you'll have to use Pinax without virtualenv support, as the general idea of using virtualenv in this way would be to create a custom environment for your Pinax application, which as I mentioned here is impossible to instruct the server to use. "

Comment: why do you want to run it without virtualenv?

Comment: Edited above to explain problem plus mediatemple response.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 0.9a1, Pinax can be used without pinax-boot.py which was the virtualenv dependency (we bundled it). Requirements are project-level and must be installed with pip. However, `setup_project` does enforce a virtual environment when installing requirements (it calls pip for you as a convenience; I would be open to not enforcing a virtual environment here). You can pass `--no-reqs` to `setup_project` forcing it to skip dependency installation. You can then run pip yourself and install it however you like.

Answer (score -1):

technically yes, but you would have to change out quite a bit of the configuration that is handed out and hand install a lot of libraries. Pinax has virtualenv as a very low level built in assumption.

Comment: Could you point out which libraries?

Its because MediaTemple will not allow virtualenv on its shared hosting package. But simple django works great.

Comment: Pinax does NOT have virtualenv as a very low level built in assumption. From 0.9, Pinax can be run without virtualenv.

Comment: Quite correct as Brian Rosner points out. Older versions made this more difficult, but apparently current versions have more flexibility there.

Answer (score -1):

you can, all you need to do is find out what is in the virtualenv.  set it up and install yolk in the virtual env and type yolk -l to see what you need to install to get it to work.

Comment: could you elaborate? How do I install yolk in virtualenv?

Do I instal it using pip in the pinax-virtualenv directory and activate the virtualenv?

Comment: The other way to get at the same information is to invoke "pip freeze" from that virtual environment. It'll detail out similar information, although not as verbose. Yolk does a nicer job detailing it all out with dependencies.

If you want to install yolk in the virtualenv, "pip install yolk" once you've activated it should do the trick.